Azure Synapse Analytics: Can't find Apache Spark Pool
MS have sent us a notification that the version of Apache Spark we are using (version 3.1) in our Azure Synapse Analytics workspace is being deprecated and we should upgrade.
However, I have never setup an Apache Spark Pool in our solution.
All the online docs point to upgrading Apache Spark pools.
If none are listed how do I do it?
When I view "Apache Spark pools" in the Monitor blade of ASA Studio there are none listed:
Apache Spark pools
But, we do have "Apache Spark applications":
Apache Spark applications
From here I can view a "Spark History Server" so it looks like its using it somewhere.
Confusingly this suggests it is using version 3.3 anyway?!?!?!
Spark History Server
I am assuming that in the background there is a Microsoft managed Spark Pool that I cannot access or upgrade and this is what I can see through the Apache Spark applications.
Therefore, there is nothing I can or should do??
